# Is it possible to enlarge text in the console in C++

Tags: c++, text

I was just wondering if you can enlarge the console text in C++ because i am writing a game and i want the game title to be printed out enlarged to give the feel of a real text based adventure game.

Comment: In Windows Vista and up, you can use [`SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200(v=vs.85).aspx). I don't think there's anything for below Vista. You can always try your hand at ASCII art.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ASCII art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) because

a) It will work and

b) You'll get that authentic text-based adventure look.

Comment: have you got any tutorials or examples.  Ive never used ASCII art before.

Comment: It's literally decades since I did anything with ASCII art, so I can't recommend any web tutorials, but [Google turns up lots of hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=ascii+art+tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot of text related things using termcaps under UNIX systems. However i don't know how it works under windows systems... Here is the [termcaps library documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_chapter/termcap_2.html).